# load_weights_from_hdf5_group original_keras_version AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, keras, load, bert-language-model

try to load saved weights

```
robertamodel = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base",num_labels=6)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('0accuracy')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5,epsilon=1e-08)

robertamodel.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=[metric])
robertamodel.load_weights(r"/media/sh/robert_model6classes.h5")
```

i get error

load_weights_from_hdf5_group original_keras_version

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 0):

try this as this helped me too:

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```